# How to compose external command in julia using concatenation of different variables?

Tags: julia

i'd like to do something like :

```
arg= " -l "
cmd = "ls $arg "
run(cmd)
```

but i can find no simple solution to do that :

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

julia> arg=" -l "
" -l "

julia> cmd=`ls $arg`
`ls ' -l '`

julia> run(cmd)
ls: cannot access  -l : No such file or directory
ERROR: failed process: Process(`ls ' -l '`, ProcessExited(2)) [2]
Stacktrace:
 [1] pipeline_error(::Base.Process) at ./process.jl:682
 [2] run(::Cmd) at ./process.jl:651

julia> cmd="ls $arg"
"ls  -l "

julia> run(`$cmd`)
ERROR: could not spawn `'ls  -l '`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
Stacktrace:
 [1] _jl_spawn(::String, ::Array{String,1}, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Base.Process, ::RawFD, ::RawFD, ::RawFD) at ./process.jl:360
 [2] #373 at ./process.jl:512 [inlined]
 [3] setup_stdio(::Base.##373#374{Cmd}, ::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:499
 [4] #spawn#372(::Nullable{Base.ProcessChain}, ::Function, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:511
 [5] run(::Cmd) at ./process.jl:650
```

should i split the resulting string to separate each part (cause there is no shell doing the job ?)

by the way, how to get the exit status of the command ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Try `arg = "-l"` instead of `arg = " -l "`. The spaces confused `ls`. Also, look at [Running External Programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/) from the manual.

Comment: i think it's the same problem. you mean like that : julia> arg="-l"
    "-l"
    
    julia> cmd="ls $arg"
    "ls -l"
    
    julia> run(`$cmd`)
    ERROR: could not spawn `'ls -l'`: no such file or directory (ENOENT),

Comment: Use `cmd=\`ls $arg\`` (with backticks)

Comment: no better... (backticks are remove in my comment :(   )   julia> arg=" -l "
" -l "

julia> cmd=`ls $arg`
`ls ' -l '`

julia> run(cmd)
ls: impossible d'accéder à  -l : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
ERROR: failed process: Process(`ls ' -l '`, ProcessExited(2)) [2]
Stacktrace:
 [1] pipeline_error(::Base.Process) at ./process.jl:682
 [2] run(::Cmd) at ./process.jl:651

Comment: it's not so easy.... be sure to test your proposition ;)

Comment: Just cut and paste the following: `arg = "-l" ; cmd = \`ls $arg\` ; run(cmd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
arg = "-l"
cmd = `ls $arg`
run(cmd)
```

And read [running external programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/)
to understand more.

Comment: ok ! sorry for my mistakes...
and it works with more variables too :)   
`arga = "-l" ; argb = "-a" ; cmd = \`ls $arga $argb\` ; run(cmd) `

Comment: i searched the Julia doc about running external programs but did not found about the exit status... any idea ?

Comment: In the doc linked, there is a paragraph with *The run method itself returns nothing, and throws an ErrorException if the external command fails to run successfully*. Should apply (though I haven't tried it now)

Comment: ok. so it's still a bit hard to use for real cases.
it's confusing too not to be able to use something like :
`arg = "-l -a"`

Comment: Perhaps it is only confusing at the beginning. You might want to try: `args = ["-l","-a"] ; cmd = \`ls $args\` ; run(cmd)`. This also enables you to have spaces in arguments and filenames, something which a normal shell command would make difficult. Another solution is: `cmd = "ls -l -r" ; run(\`bash -c $cmd\`)` which uses the shell to run command. But the last solution depends on the specific shell and OS.